# Searching in the parent table with checkboxes (Oracle Forms Builder)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

Where could I find any info on that.

a)I'll need to select which column is being searched

b)Select what data will be displayed with check boxes

c)If the selected column(in which you search) is the primary key column, then the form will also display the child table check boxes which, if checked, will display the columns along with the checked parent table columns.

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CHAMPIONS (
  CNAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL, 
  PRICELEVEL NUMBER(1) NOT NULL, 
  ROLE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  HPLEVEL NUMBER(2) NOT NULL, 
  ATKLEVEL NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
  MAGICLEVEL NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
  DIFFLEVEL NUMBER(2) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE SKINS (
  SNAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  CNAME VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
  PRICELEVEL NUMBER(1) NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE Champions ADD CONSTRAINT pk_Champions PRIMARY KEY (CNAME);

ALTER TABLE Skins ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Skins FOREIGN KEY (CNAME) REFERENCES champions(CNAME);
```

I don't really care how this is implemented since i don't know which way is possible. Since it's just a 1-1 relationship, some sort of hiding might work.

[image: The form i'd like]

if the pressed button is cname(the primary key) the first result table will of course have only one row while the second result table will be populated by the data associated with the selected primary key. If any other button is pressed the other table isn't even displayed however the first one might have multiple rows displayed. The columns that are displayed in the results depend on the check boxes

Comment: You want to dynamically create checkboxes with the columns(name of columns?) of a given table?

Comment: updated the question with more info

Comment: Still not clear to me what view you want to do. A skin exists only for one champion?

Comment: added how i want it to look. Doesn't have to be exact if the form builder isn't capable of it

Comment: There are 23 different champions. Each of them can have from 0 to x number of skins in the child table. So if you search in the cname column with "AHRI", you get the information about her from the parent table and you get a list of all her skins and skin pricelevels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat the champion data displayed, create two separated database blocks,  and add a relation between them.

If you want to display all data in one multi-row block, you will need a view that joins the data from the two tables.

Your search options will be a non-database block. When you click in the search button, you will need to change the `default_where` of the blocks, adding the value searched according to the field. For this, you will need to add the trigger `pre-query`. Something like:

**trigger of search button**

```
begin
  go_block('champions_block');
  execute_query; -- this triggers pre-query of champions_block
end;
```

**trigger pre-query**

```
if :search.search_text is not null then
  -- this changes the where of your block
  set_block_property('champions_block',default_where, 'cname like %'||:search.search_text||'%');  
  --
else
  -- remove previous where
  set_block_property('champions_block',default_where, '');
end if;
```

The show / hide of fields is more complicated, you will need to show / hide the items using:

```
set_item_property('name_of_block.name_of_item', visible, property_true); -- false to hide
```

And also will need to adjust the position of the other fields:

```
set_item_property('name_of_block.name_of_item', position, pos_x, pos_y);
```